# When should I add red chili to an omelette?

Tags: eggs, mixing

Is there a proper time to add red chili to an omelette?  How should it be mixed in?

Comment: I assumed you meant chopped chillies in some form, the other answer assumes powder. You may wish to clarify.

Comment: Many would say never.

Comment: Paprika, one of several types of powdered red chili, is often pretty tasty in an omelette. You can put it on the finished product too. -makes it look Haute. If you can, grow your own paprika. It's tone better than the stuff that's sat in ship holds and warehouses for years. No worries about red lead contamination then either.

Answer (score 3):

Chili powder will never dissolve in eggs. What you're aiming for is a suspension: the chili particles evenly distributed in the eggs. The chili will eventually float to the surface of an egg mix, so the best you can do is mix it properly right before pouring it into the skillet, and hope it sets before the chili separates too much.

Comment: ... or use chilli oil, to whisk into the mix, or fry in (random late-night snack idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

I often add chopped chilli to an omelette. Fresh or dried (flakes) can simply be stirred into the egg before cooking. The latter is particularly convenient.

Another approach I take is to fry onions/peppers/mushrooms, chilli and/or garlic first, until soft, set them aside and cook the omelette in the same pan (with more oil). Just before folding the omelette in half, put the veg and possibly cheese on top of one side. This is overkill for chillies alone, unless you like a huge quantity.